# JSON file will not show output in application

Tags: android, mysql, json

I am trying to parse a json file generated by mysql into my android application. The screen doesn't show anything at all. I can pull the json file directly in a browser and it outputs the data. I am unsure why I cannot see it in the application. I will add the applicable code here if someone wants to take a look.

Logcat

```js
12-02 23:54:10.444 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 60.317ms
12-02 23:54:10.586 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts E/c3+U6b5T6IHUG94DJ22teQVKojk=:: PMSeT4Q8FLTjYUOwNpnShvIlw4E=
12-02 23:54:10.642 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 28.796ms
12-02 23:54:10.843 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.736ms
12-02 23:54:11.102 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 56.667ms
12-02 23:54:11.294 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.199ms
12-02 23:54:11.595 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 78.174ms
12-02 23:54:11.648 2379-2390/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 32.152ms
12-02 23:54:11.720 2379-2390/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16851(1095KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(160KB) LOS objects, 58% free, 1549KB/3MB, paused 72.392ms total 254.775ms
12-02 23:54:11.733 2379-2390/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.266ms
12-02 23:54:11.837 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 32.684ms
12-02 23:54:12.008 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts D/BTFX Alerts: Creating IAB helper.
12-02 23:54:12.013 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts D/BTFX Alerts: Starting setup.
12-02 23:54:12.013 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts D/IabHelper: Starting in-app billing setup.
12-02 23:54:12.017 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts D/BTFX Alerts: Setup finished.
12-02 23:54:12.017 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts E/BTFX Alerts: **** BTFX Alerts Error: Problem setting up in-app billing: IabResult: Billing service unavailable on device. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)
12-02 23:54:12.017 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts D/BTFX Alerts: Showing alert dialog: Error: Problem setting up in-app billing: IabResult: Billing service unavailable on device. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)
12-02 23:54:12.039 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-02 23:54:12.306 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 83.896ms
12-02 23:54:12.513 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.090ms
12-02 23:54:12.678 2379-2456/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185470
12-02 23:54:12.793 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 28.924ms
12-02 23:54:12.866 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 23:54:12.984 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-02 23:54:13.322 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-02 23:54:13.322 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad760120, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-02 23:54:13.452 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-02 23:54:13.452 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3f9ece0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-02 23:54:13.586 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 23:54:14.275 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts I/Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 23:54:20.201 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab79e080
12-02 23:54:20.247 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
12-02 23:54:22.122 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-02 23:54:22.122 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa11fec60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-02 23:54:22.625 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab79e0f0
12-02 23:54:26.348 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.880ms
12-02 23:54:26.514 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-02 23:54:26.514 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa0afc040, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-02 23:54:26.556 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 47.918ms
12-02 23:54:27.095 2379-2447/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab79e160
12-02 23:54:27.284 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts D/Volley: [1] 1.onResponse: AlertMainActivity
12-02 23:54:27.284 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for profilePic
12-02 23:54:27.285 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
12-02 23:54:27.285 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
12-02 23:54:27.285 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts.AlertMainActivity.parseJsonFeed(AlertMainActivity.java:113)
12-02 23:54:27.285 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts.AlertMainActivity.access$100(AlertMainActivity.java:31)
12-02 23:54:27.285 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts.AlertMainActivity$1.onResponse(AlertMainActivity.java:77)
12-02 23:54:27.285 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts.AlertMainActivity$1.onResponse(AlertMainActivity.java:71)
12-02 23:54:27.285 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
12-02 23:54:27.285 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
12-02 23:54:27.285 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-02 23:54:27.286 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-02 23:54:27.286 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-02 23:54:27.286 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-02 23:54:27.286 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-02 23:54:27.286 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-02 23:54:27.286 2379-2379/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-02 23:55:09.625 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.831ms
12-03 00:01:53.397 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 27.544ms
12-03 00:13:46.829 2379-2386/com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.750ms
```

MainActivity - Parses json

```js
package com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts;

import com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts.adapter.FeedListAdapter;
import com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts.app.AppController;
import com.brasiltradefx.btfxalerts.data.FeedItem;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Cache.Entry;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;


/**
 * Created by Deryk on 12/2/2015.
 */
public class AlertMainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = AlertMainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://www.contrariantradefx.info/android/btfxalerts/alert.json";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // These two lines not needed,
        // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
        //getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
        //getActionBar().setIcon(
                //new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {
                        parseJsonFeed(response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("alert");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setOrder_type(feedObj.getString("order_type"));
                item.setPair(feedObj.getString("pair"));
                item.setRate(feedObj.getString("rate"));
                item.setQuick_target(feedObj.getString("quick_target"));
                item.setLong_target(feedObj.getString("long_target"));
                item.setStop_loss(feedObj.getString("stop_loss"));
                item.setBreak_Even(feedObj.getString("break_even"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));


                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapter
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

FeedItem class - Here I notice that FeedItem on line 13 is light grey. It has an error saying it is not used.

```js
public class FeedItem {
    private int id;
    private String name, status, image, profilePic, timeStamp, url, order_type, pair, rate, quick_target, long_target, stop_loss, break_even;

    public FeedItem() {
    }

    public FeedItem(int id, String name, String image, String status,
                    String profilePic, String timeStamp, String url, String order_type, String pair, String rate, String quick_target, String long_target,
    String stop_loss, String break_even) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.status = status;
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.url = url;
        this.order_type = order_type;
        this.pair = pair;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.quick_target = quick_target;
        this.long_target = long_target;
        this.stop_loss = stop_loss;
        this.break_even = break_even;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImge() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImge(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getProfilePic() {
        return profilePic;
    }

    public void setProfilePic(String profilePic) {
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getOrder_type() {
        return order_type;
    }

    public void setOrder_type(String order_type) {
        this.order_type = order_type;
    }

    public String getPair() {
        return pair;
    }

    public void setPair(String pair) {
        this.pair = pair;
    }

    public String getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(String rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public String getQuick_target() {
        return quick_target;
    }

    public void setQuick_target(String quick_target) {
        this.quick_target = quick_target;
    }

    public String getLong_target() {
        return long_target;
    }

    public void setLong_target(String long_target) {
        this.long_target = long_target;
    }

    public String getStop_loss() {
        return stop_loss;
    }

    public void setStop_loss(String stop_loss) {
        this.stop_loss = stop_loss;
    }

    public String getBreak_Even() {
        return break_even;
    }

    public void setBreak_Even(String break_even) { this.break_even = break_even; }
}
```

FeedListAdapter

```js
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);

        TextView order_type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOrderType);
        TextView pair = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPair);
        TextView rate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtRate);
        TextView quick_target = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuick_Target);
        TextView long_target = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLong_Target);
        TextView stop_loss = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtStop_Loss);
        TextView break_even = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBreak_Even);
        NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getName());
        order_type.setText(item.getOrder_type());
        pair.setText(item.getPair());
        rate.setText(item.getRate());
        quick_target.setText(item.getQuick_target());
        long_target.setText(item.getLong_target());
        stop_loss.setText(item.getStop_loss());
        break_even.setText(item.getBreak_Even());

        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // user profile pic
        profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: getview method is called ? is it parsed properly and the values received in adapter correct?

Comment: listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter); call this after the for loop in parsing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really new, so I am not sure exactly how to do that. I was following a tutorial and this is the way it was designed. Here is the link. Maybe that will help because the author explains what he is actually doing in each piece. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/0/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/

Comment: Logcat clearly says: `org.json.JSONException: No value for profilePic`. So there is no such key in your json, which could be either because you made a typo, it exists on a different level in the data structure, or it's optional. Without knowing what the json looks like, it's up to you to 'fix' this, which should be easy enough now that you know where to look.

Comment: Yup as MH says the value is null for profilpic need to be wrapped around with the null check. the tag does exist in JSON though or use optString instead of getString.

Comment: I appreciate the help guys. I did see that it said the profilepic was null. I thought it was because the field in the database was empty. I added a url for the profile pic, but it still didn't show. I will take a look at this again and see if I can fix that.